# facebook API: manage_pages permission is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to pull the list of pages from an account by using my App. I took reference from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

I have added few scopes "**manage_pages, publish_stream, read_stream, publish_actions, publish_pages**" to **fb:login-button** so that I can pull pages. I have added one more function

```
function getFacebookPages() {
   FB.api('/me/accounts', function( apiResponse ) {
       if( apiResponse && !apiResponse.error ) {
          console.log('For Facebook pages');
          console.log(apiResponse);
      }
  });
}
```

to pull pages, but it not pulling pages.

Please help me.

Comment: Which email account are you using? The one you have registered the app with ?  Have you tried running this in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ Graph explorer?

Comment: I am trying to pull my personal accounts pages trough an App. Ideally when we define scopes like "manage_pages, publish_pages" It usually ask to allow access for these permission at first login.  But It never ask in my case and when I checked the permission by using FB.api('/me/permissions' , function( apiResponse ) { console.log(apiResponse); }); It always shows only default permission 'public_profile' as granted.

Comment: I had gone through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review where in video, it gives me some information related with changes in permission and  that information need to be submitted to Facebook team. But I did not suggest what and how can we made this changes.

Answer (score 11):

For **permissions**  that aren't the default ones ( email, public_profile, user_friends ) you need in 'Status & Review'(from the menu in your app dashboard) to  make a **submission** for them.

Until your review is completed you could create in your app a TEST app at 'Test Apps' ( again, from the menu in your app dashboard ). If you code using the ids of an test app you don't need the submission for permissions, just specify them in the scope.

This must work, please give more details if doesn't works